# Joomla CSRF form validation

Tags: component, form, session, security-token

I have noticed this happen occasionally with a component I am working on. I use `JHtml::_('form.token')` in the form and `JSession::checkToken() or die('Invalid Token')` to check it once i receive the form data.

So it is triggering the die every time. One thought I have is that on the same page is a login form that uses form tokens (that form works). They also both use the same token.

Has something changed since this article http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_add_CSRF_anti-spoofing_to_forms was published on how to use CSRF? For how simple it is to implement I just fail to see any way what I am doing is "failing".

I am using the latest version of Joomla (3.3.6 at the time of this posting).

UPDATE: Forgot to say, the form always uses `POST`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FoF has a handy **_csrfProtection** routine in the controller, with several ways to check the token:

- JUtility::getToken() (for Joomla 2.5, removed from Joomla 3.x)
- $session->getToken()
- $session->getFormToken()
- or, the _token field in any of the previous instances

https://github.com/akeeba/fof/blob/development/fof/controller/controller.php#L3308

Comment: `JUtility::getToken()` has been removed from Joomla 3.x ;)

Comment: Yes, in FoF controller, there are several checks to support Joomla 2.5/3 in the same _csrfProtection.

Comment: I do rely on FoF to an extent for other things, I will check into this.

Comment: Looked into it and noticed that the `JSession::checkToken()` was not returning "true", however doing it the same way FoF was bypassed that issue.

Answer (score 2):

Is it possible hat you submit your form with the "GET" method?

Because JSession::checkToken only validates against "POST" method, you have to use

```
JSession::checkToken('get') or die();
```

if you like to check the GET requests.

Comment: Not using `GET`, but good answer. Should of included that it was using `POST` in the question as well.